# How do I set an orientation specific background in a Windows Store Application?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store Application where I've been supplied a different background image asset depending on whether the app is running in Portrait or Landscape mode.

Other than this background image, there are no other orientation specific differences.

What is the tidiest way to implement this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in `Window.Current.SizeChanged` handler:

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (ApplicationView.Value == ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```